# Can sessionStorage.getItem('key') trigger an exception? incognito mode? Any old mobile phone browser?

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, session-storage

I'm curious if `sessionStorage.getItem('mytestdata')` **ever** can trigger an exception.
I'm NOT talking about

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')
```

but rather about

```
sessionStorage.getItem('key')
```

Thank you.

Comment: In a really old browser where `sessionStorage` is not defined, that statement should cause an error along the lines of `ReferenceError: sessionStorage is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but just if you are using a very old version of web browser, not if a key doesn't exists.
You can check compatibility here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: thank you but I'm not asking about the compatibility. It could be incompatible but return simply null instead of causing an exception.

Comment: On Firefox, Chrome and IE it doesn't throw an exception when key is not null. (Sorry if it isn't the answer that you want, my english is bad)

Answer (score 0):

If any item not set in `localstorage` then you need to check it by `typeof != 'undefined'`

```
if(typeof sessionStorage.getItem('key') !== null){
  //The `key` is set in the `localStorage`
}

if(typeof sessionStorage.getItem('key') != 'undefined'){
   //The `key` and `value` both are set in the `localStorage`    
}
```